# How to fetch the url content using php curl or file_get_content on the same server?

Tags: php, caching, curl, file-get-contents

I have some code to convert a PHP page to HTML:

```
$dynamic = "http://website.net/home.php";
$out = "home.html" ;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"$dynamic");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$file = curl_exec($ch);

file_put_contents($out, $file);
```

This works perfect in localhost but it takes too much time/doesn't work on the live site.

I've tried `php_get_contents`, but that also doesn't work.

Note:

- `http://website.net/home.php` page is in the same site where the code is hosted.
- `curl` is **enabled** and `allow_url_fopen` is **on** as per `phpinfo()` in both localhost and at server.

**EDIT:**

- It works fine when using **other website's** page instead of my website.
- The site's target page perfectly loads in my browser.

The web page of my website is loading fast as usual but when I use `curl` or `file_get_contents`, it's too slow and even can't get output.

Comment: check your server phpinfo() curl support = enabled and allow_url_fopen=on

Comment: sure `allow_url_fopen = on` on the host / server?

Comment: curl is enabled and allow_url_fopen is on

Comment: also close your curl after exec

Comment: @Touregsys Still not working.

Comment: what do you want to with this page("http://website.net/home.php") ?

Comment: The `home.php` page is dynamic page of my website and i want to converting it into static.

Comment: did you check the return code that is being sent by cURL?

Comment: The return code is neither `true` nor `false`.

Comment: Does visiting http://website.net/home.php also trigger the CURL process? - are you creating an infinite loop by calling it and then having it call itself?

Also, I assume that http://website.net/home.php is not the real URL, can the web server that is running CURL actually resolve the domain name of your  real URL?

Comment: @RussWilde Website.net/home.php doen't trigger any CURL process .. It does having just some mysql database retrievals.

Comment: Use command `ping website.net`. Incase your are not getting response add host entry for `website.net` in `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: @rajeshujade The side loads as smooth as butter in my machine. Also the ping is good.

Comment: Make sure your server can resolve itself. Sounds like a DNS issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have DNS resolving problem.

There is two ways you can use your website's locahost instead of the external domain name.

**1. If you have your own server / VPS / Dedicated server**,
 Add entry in `vim /etc/hosts` for 127.0.0.1 website.net or try to fetch the content with localhost(127.0.0.1).

**2. If you are using shared hosting**, then try to use below `url(s)` in your code,

```
http://localhost.mywebsite.net/~username/home.php. 
OR
Try to call http://localhost.mywebsite.net/home.php
```

Try this to fetch the url content -

```
$dynamic = TRY_ABOVE_URL(S)
$out = "home.html" ;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$dynamic);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$file = curl_exec($ch);

if($file === false) {
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}

file_put_contents($out, $file);
```

Comment: PHP error `Warning: file_put_contents( .... html content ...  at line   file_put_contents($result['content'], $out);`

Answer (score 0):

To investigate the reason why is it not working on live server, Try this:

```
$dynamic = "http://website.net/home.php";

$out     = "home.html" ;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $dynamic);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$file = curl_exec($ch);

if($file === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch); 

file_put_contents($out, $file);
```

Comment: are you able to see any error by curl_error function? Add <?php ini_set('display_errors', 1);error_reporting(E_ALL); ?> in the beginning of script.

Comment: Even curl function returns neight true nor false

Comment: did you added `ini_set('display_errors', 1);error_reporting(E_ALL);` in the beginning of script? Also, I updated the code, please use updated one.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the provider SSL configuration.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
```

Check for know smth. about SSL configuration of your provider.

Comment: I don't thinks it will depend on provider SSL configuration

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
file_put_contents("home.html", fopen("http://website.net/home.php", 'r'));
```

but curl should work as well. If you have SSH access to the server, try to resolve your domain name using ping or something. It is possible to have a local DNS issue - it will explain why you can download from external domains.

For my example, you'll need `allow_fopen_url` to be On, so please verify that by `phpinfo()` first.

Comment: Page loading and loading and after several minutes it says `Connection timed out in file.php at line xx`.

Comment: And on line xx you have the file_put_contents... ? I think that your troubles are caused by an DNS issue. Could you do `echo gethostbyname("yourdomainname.com");` and match it with the actual IP which your website translates into?

Comment: It returns the ip address of server, and yest it matches.

Comment: Please re-attempt with `curl` and `file_put_contents`, but add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);` just before `curl_exec($ch);`, and also `print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));` right after `curl_exec($ch);` and post the result.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is a network routing issue, basically the server can't find a route to website.net(itself). This has is a server issue and not a PHP issue. The quickest solution is to edit the hosts file on the server and set website.net to 127.0.0.1.

On linux servers you will need to add the following line to the bottom of /etc/hosts to:

```
127.0.0.1 website.net
```

Alternatively you can try fetching `http://127.0.0.1/home.php` but that will not work if you have multiple virtual hosts on the server.

Comment: The php script is hosted at `http://website.net` itself.. it is not using external website

Comment: why can't server can't access itself

Comment: But at shared server editing hosts file is not possible

Comment: It's trying to access the external IP address and can't find a way to it, it's similar to not finding the front door of your own house while looking out the window. By editing /etc/hosts you are telling the server that website.net is on the server itself and not outside it. If this is on a shared server then the service provider must fix the routing.

Comment: Have you tried with external IP address? If that works then this is a routing issue, not PHP issue.

Comment: External and internal ip addresses are both same.

Comment: I mean with another IP address, for instance fetching: `http://www.google.is/images/srpr/logo11w.png`

Comment: Yes... with external websites/ip_address the content is fetching.

Comment: Then this is a routing issue with the server and the network. You can't in any way bypass this in PHP, only the server and/or network administrators can fix this. You could use ob_start() and ob_get_clean() to fetch any output into PHP variable and save that.